# What is the purpose of providing miracles?

Tags: allah, belief

Based on some answers here on this website and on other websites and my basic knowledge of Islam I have come to the following speculative idea (Please correct me if the idea is wrong):

Islam is an act of submission to God. It is a humbling experience for the muslim believer to submit to God, where the human should willingly submit his powers to god the creator of everything. These powers include finances, social status, body, and most importantly (for the sake of this question) mental power. This is why god refuses to provide decisive evidence (like a mathematical or a scientific proof) for his existence or for the truth of his messengers. Out of his pride he refuses to give decisive evidence, but out of his mercy he accepts to give only suggestive hints. If the human believes in him even despite of lack of decisive proofs, this is also when the worshiper was  humble enough to submit his/her mind to god . I see evidence for this speculative idea in the following examples:

1. In the story of prophet Moses: When Egypt's Pharaoh tried to admit belief in god while drowning after seeing the miracle of sea splitting, his attempt to believe was rejected by God.
2. In one of the Prophet's sayings (PBUH) that people's believes after the sun rises from the west will no longer be accepted.

Question 1: Is my speculative idea correct ?

Question 2: In case the answer to question 1 is yes, then why does god provide miracles as evidence of him if belief using miracles as evidence will be rejected ?

Comment: @UmH What is your answer to question 1 in my post ?

Answer (score 1):

> Out of his pride he refuses to give decisive evidence.

Please avoid to express the ideas of God by yourself or by quoting someone's else opinion other than of Qur'an and of those who know the true knowledge of Qur'an (Prophet and his Ahl-ul-Bayt).

> This is why god refuses to provide decisive evidence (like a mathematical or a scientific proof) for his existence or for the truth of his messengers.

No! There are many scholars who believe that Qur'an, which is a miracle, is the book of knowledge. The Qur'an itself mentions many times that it is the proof for the religion, though not necessarily understood by many ( or all  ?) of us.

> The month of Ramadhan [is that] in which was revealed the Qur’an, a **guidance for the people and clear proofs of guidance and criterion.** [2:185]

> ...certainly **revealed to you verses [which are] clear proofs** and no one would deny them except the defiantly disobedient. [2:99]

( Above verses can be translated in other ways also )

Coming to your questions, yes , your speculations are false because you seem to imply that God rejects all the beliefs which come through miracles, which is certainly wrong. For example, many magicians came to the side of Moses after seeing his miracles , jesus cured many people through miracles. Infact, miracles are themselves one of the proofs of prophethood.

Regarding your questions, they are interpreted to refer people who were transgressors and defiantly disobedient, who were invited through multiple miracles to the religion but their appetite of proofs had transgressed the order of Allah.